# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1' solution

Tags: python, typeerror

The code below is my Final Year Project for Complaint Admission. I have encountered some problems which i have already done some research on how to solve it but after trying both potential solution, it seems the error are coming out as the final result. below is the coding line

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *
    from tkinter.messagebox import *
    from db import DBConnect
    from listComp import ListComp
    
    #Config
    conn = DBConnect()
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('600x285')
    root.title('Sistem Aduan Makmal Komputer')
    root.configure(background='#AEB6BF')
    
    #Style
    style = Style()
    style.theme_use('clam')
    for elem in ['TLabel', 'TButton', 'TRadioutton']:
        style.configure(elem, background='#AEB6BF')
    
    #Gridx1354
    labels = ['Full Name:', 'Gender:', 'Comment:', 'Test:']
    for i in range(4):
        Label(root, text=labels[i]).grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    
    BuList = Button(root, text='List Comp.')
    BuList.grid(row=4, column=1)
    BuSubmit = Button(root, text='Submit Now')
    BuSubmit.grid(row=4, column=2)
    
    #Entries
    fullname = Entry(root, width=30, font=('Times New Roman', 12))
    fullname.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
    SpanGender = StringVar()
    Radiobutton(root, text='Male', value='male', variable=SpanGender).grid(row=1, column=1)
    Radiobutton(root, text='Female', value='female', variable=SpanGender).grid(row=1, column=2)
    comment = Text(root, width=35, height=5, font=('Times New Roman', 12))
    comment.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)
    test = Entry(root, width=30, font=('Times New Roman', 12))
    test.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)
    
    def SaveData():
        msg = conn.Add(fullname.get(), SpanGender.get(), comment.get(), test.get(1.0, 'end-1c'))
        fullname.delete(0, 'end')
        comment.delete(0, 'end')
        test.delete(1.0, 'end-1c')
        showinfo(title='Add Info', message=msg)
    
    def ShowList():
        listrequest = ListComp()
    
    
    BuSubmit.config(command=SaveData)
    BuList.config(command=ShowList)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

In the Code above I have already done the option like `1.0, 'end'` and also `1.0, 'end-1c'` but I still got the "TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1" at the end of the result. Please help. Much Love.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341) as well as expected output and minimal code. You can [edit] if needed.